# Chromecast HLS stream without audio

Tags: chromecast, http-live-streaming

Can Chromecast play HLS stream with H264 video codec and without audio stream in it?

When I have created HLS stream without audio in it with supported H264 Baseline profile, I am able to play same stream on my vlc player with m3u8 file but same video I am not able to play on chromecast default receiver.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It seems ChromeCast does not support HLS without audio.

The interesting thing is that if we want to play a simple video (e.g. mp4) without audio, ChromeCast is able to play it.

To cope with that issue I suggest to add a silent audio track to your TS files. Using FFMPEG you can add a silent audio track adding `-f lavfi -i anullsrc` parameters into your command line to create m3u8 files.

You can find more information about `anullsrc` here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Null

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) are the supported Media for Google Cast.

Video codecs (Chromecast 1st and 2nd Gen.)

- H.264 High Profile up to level 4.1 (the processor can decode up to
  720p/60fps or 1080p/30fps)

Delivery methods and adaptive streaming protocols

HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)

- AES-128 encryption
- Raw MP3 segments can be part of an HLS media playlist

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing detail about codec but I am playing supported video format only but without audio.